# AutoComplete TextView removes RecyclerView from the same page

Tags: java, android

I have just added an AutoCompleteTextview to my `activity_main_page` but before that i had a `recyclerview` on the same page that displayed images in a horizontal list. But now, after adding the `AutoCompleteTextview`, no images or `recylcerview` is showing up.

I want it show both the AutoCompleteTextview and the images that i had before in its original form(horizontal list)

Here is the activity_main_page

```
<RelativeLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.abc.hotelomania.MainPage"

>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background = "@drawable/indian_naval_bases1"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:theme ="@style/translucent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:hint="Search City"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:completionThreshold="2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve here. If you want the image to be fullscreen in the background with a drawable juste use background attribut in your relativelayout. If you don't see the recyclerview anymore it's probably the image hiding it being on top.

Comment: the images that were being shown in `horizontal listview` aren't showing up ever since i put the `autocompletetextview.` I dont know why is that. Does the autocompletetextview take up all the space on the screen? I dont know why this situation is happening

Comment: You are not realy clear in what you are asking. Are you talking about `indian_naval_bases1` ?